# warning: 'UITabBarController' may not respond to 'select Tab:'

Tags: xcode

warning: 'UITabBarController' may not respond to 'select Tab:'

I am always getting a warning message like this in xcode 4.2 is there any possibilities to remove this warning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because there is no "`selectTab`" API.

The closest thing within "`UITabBarController`" that might match what you are trying to do might be the [`selectedIndex`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITabBarController/selectedIndex) property.